# More class field theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

The classical language of class field theory can be generalized by class formation. So far I've seen, for example, the absolute Galois group acting on the multiplicative group of a local field, or the group of ideles of a global field. I also know there is something like [geometric class field theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73054/a-reference-for-geometric-class-field-theory?_gl=1*opos5*_ga*MTUyNjgyNTk4MC4xNjA5NTI1Nzcx*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4MjIxMTMyNS42MjguMS4xNjgyMjEyMTQzLjAuMC4w) that describes etale isogenies of commutative algebraic groups and finite abelian geometrically connected coverings of an algebraic curve over a perfect field which looks very deep for me.

I am curious about **if there is other example of class field theory and is there any reference**? For example, the theory for covering space is almost the same as Galois theory for fields, so I guess there could be a topological class field theory? Maybe for general topological spaces this might be hard, but what about something like manifolds?

Comment: Would you consider generalizations of class field theory to be "other examples" of it?  See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66500/why-is-class-field-theory-the-same-as-langlands-for-gl-1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849429/concrete-example-of-non-abelian-class-field-theory-why-langlands-program-is

Comment: @KCd The posts look very helpful! I see how Langlands program generalizes class field theory by looking at higher dimensional representations, but is there something like a class formation?

Comment: The Langlands program is still largely conjectural, so one can't treat it as a topic with all the necessary machinery in place like class field theory for the abelian case. Moreover, the proofs of class field theory often start by checking a property for cyclic extensions and then working out the case of abelian extensions via reduction to the cyclic case thanks to every finite abelian group being a direct product of cyclic groups. There's nothing at all like that for nonabelian Galois extensions.